# How to add multiple wallets for reflections (Developer, marketing)

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-design, ether, contract-deployment

Im and engineer learning new ways in solidity.

I would like to know how is it possible to create a coin that deducts tax and the tax automatically distributes to 2 different wallet (Developer, marketing).

How can it be done? Can remix do that? Can trustswap do that? cannot seems to find a clear answer and direction.

Your help is appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Could you please provide more details on what you're trying to accomplish? I'm assuming by tax you mean that the developer's address and the marketer's address receive a cut after calling a payable function? Is the function call payable or are the transactions being mediated through an ERC20 token?

Comment: Yes this is correct, and im assuming it should be payable, all i want to accomplish is after every buy/sell a cut of the money should go to different wallets. Thank you